# Google Visualization will only draw 1 of 2 charts

Tags: google-visualization

I've created a set of google gauges that pull data from a google sheet.  The sheet has two pages, the first holds the values that initially load into the gauges, the second has the data that feed the changed value of each gauge.  The buttons at the bottom allow the gauges to be toggled back and forth between the two values.

I've only been able to animate gauges from a google sheet this way using the chartWrapper class, and the .setDataSourceUrl method.

I would like to add a data table underneath the gauges, but cannot get both chartWrappers to draw simultaneously.  I can draw one or the other, but not both  I've looked and have found others with the similar issues, and have attempted the described fixes, but to no avail.  I have unique ids.  I have a div for each chart.  I call a single function that then callsOnLoad the individual functions that draw each chart separately.  I'm not sure what else to try, and it feels much like guess work at this point.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you very much for your attention!

I'm not concerned about the buttons just yet, I just want both charts to draw on the initial load.
Here's the html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Animated Gauge fed by Sheet
    </title>
    <!-- One script tag loads all the required libraries! Do not specify any chart types in the autoload statement. -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src='https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={"modules":[{"name":"visualization","version":"1"}]}'>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
      //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization); 
      //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

      //global variable manipulatedby the following 3 functions.
      var wrap = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper();
      var myTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper();      

      function drawGauge() {
        // Define the chart using setters:
        //var wrap = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper();
        wrap.setChartType('Gauge');
        wrap.setDataSourceUrl('https://docs.google.com/a/csd99.org/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkmXRMp1VYawdFVEUmJlM3AzOUM3R0NMVlBzOTN5dlE&usp=drive_web\n\&gid=0');
        wrap.setContainerId('gauge_div');
        wrap.setOptions({
                    'min': 0,
                    'max': 35,
                    //greenFrom:0,
                    //greenTo:10,
                    'yellowFrom': 15,
                    'yellowTo': 20,
                    'redFrom': 20,
                    'redTo': 30,
                    'greenColor': 999900,
                    'yellowColor': '#FFFF99',
                    'redColor': 660066,
                    'minorTicks': 10,
                    'animation':{
                       'duration': 800,
                       'easing': 'out'
                    }
                    //width of container determines whether gauges show up on same row or multiple rows
                    //'width':700
                  });
        //alert('hello');
        var elem = document.getElementById('gauge_div');
        elem.style.opacity = 0.6;
        wrap.draw();
      }  

      function drawTable(){
        myTable.setChartType('Table');        
        myTable.setContainerId('table_div');
        myTable.setDataSourceUrl('https://docs.google.com/a/csd99.org/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkmXRMp1VYawdFVEUmJlM3AzOUM3R0NMVlBzOTN5dlE&usp=drive_web\n\#gid=0&headers=1');
        myTable.setOptions({'width':200});
        //alert('hello');
        myTable.draw();
    }

      function changeValues()  {
        // Define the chart using setters:
        //var wrap = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper();
        wrap.setChartType('Gauge');
        wrap.setDataSourceUrl('https://docs.google.com/a/csd99.org/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkmXRMp1VYawdFVEUmJlM3AzOUM3R0NMVlBzOTN5dlE&usp=drive_web\n\\n\&gid=2');
        wrap.setContainerId('gauge_div');
        wrap.setOptions({
                    'min': 0,
                    'max': 35,
                    //greenFrom:0,
                    //greenTo:10,
                    'yellowFrom': 15,
                    'yellowTo': 20,
                    'redFrom': 20,
                    'redTo': 30,
                    'greenColor': 999900,
                    'yellowColor': '#FFFF99',
                    'redColor': 660066,
                    'minorTicks': 10,
                    'animation':{
                       'duration': 800,
                       'easing': 'out'
                    }

                    //width of container determines whether gauges show up on same row or multiple rows
                    //'width':700
                  });
        //alert('hello');
        var elem = document.getElementById('gauge_div');
        elem.style.opacity = 1.0;
        wrap.draw();  
      }

      function changeValuesBack()  {
        // Define the chart using setters:
        //var wrap = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper();
        wrap.setChartType('Gauge');
        wrap.setDataSourceUrl('https://docs.google.com/a/csd99.org/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkmXRMp1VYawdFVEUmJlM3AzOUM3R0NMVlBzOTN5dlE&usp=drive_web\n\\n\&gid=0');
        wrap.setContainerId('gauge_div');
        wrap.setOptions({
                    'min': 0,
                    'max': 35,
                    //greenFrom:0,
                    //greenTo:10,
                    'yellowFrom': 15,
                    'yellowTo': 20,
                    'redFrom': 20,
                    'redTo': 30,
                    'greenColor': 999900,
                    'yellowColor': '#FFFF99',
                    'redColor': 660066,
                    'minorTicks': 10,
                    'animation':{
                       'duration': 800,
                       'easing': 'out'
                    }

                    //width of container determines whether gauges show up on same row or multiple rows
                    //'width':700
                  });
        //alert('hello');
        var elem = document.getElementById('gauge_div');
        elem.style.opacity = 0.6;
        wrap.draw();  
      }

      function drawVisualization(){
          drawGauge();
          drawTable();
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Data for gauges located in this sheet on worksheets 1 and 2</h3>
    <h3><a href = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkmXRMp1VYawdFVEUmJlM3AzOUM3R0NMVlBzOTN5dlE&usp=sharing'> here.</a></h3>
    <div id='gauge_div' style='height: 150px; width: 500px;'></div>
    <div id='table_div'></div>
    <input type="button" style="opacity:0.6" value="Last Month" onclick="changeValuesBack()"/>
    <input type="button" value="This Month" onclick="changeValues()"/>    
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gauge and table ChartWrappers are being created in sync with the page loading, not as a response to the callback from the google loader, so you are likely to run into some problems there if the code runs before the API is loaded.  You also have a lot of unnecessary duplication of code and requerying the data source.  Once you have a copy of the data, you should cache it so you don't have to query the data source again, but doing that isn't possible if you use the `dataSourceUrl` property of the ChartWrappers.  Here's an example based on your code that caches each data request so you don't have to make multiple redundant queries:

[javascript]

```
function drawCharts () {
    var query1 = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/a/csd99.org/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkmXRMp1VYawdFVEUmJlM3AzOUM3R0NMVlBzOTN5dlE&usp=drive_web\n\#gid=0&headers=1');
    query1.send(function (response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }

        var data1 = response.getDataTable(), data2 = null;
        var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'Gauge',
            containerId: 'gauge_div',
            dataTable: data1,
            options: {
                min: 0,
                max: 35,
                yellowFrom: 15,
                yellowTo: 20,
                redFrom: 20,
                redTo: 30,
                greenColor: 999900,
                yellowColor: '#FFFF99',
                redColor: 660066,
                minorTicks: 10,
                animation: {
                    duration: 800,
                    easing: 'out'
                }
            }
        });
        var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'Table',
            containerId: 'table_div',
            dataTable: data1,
            options: {
                width: 200
            }
        });

        chart.draw();
        table.draw();

        var lastMonth = document.querySelector('#lastMonth');
        var thisMonth = document.querySelector('#thisMonth');

        function drawLastMonth () {
            chart.setDataTable(data1);
            table.setDataTable(data1);
            chart.draw();
            table.draw();
            lastMonth.disabled = 'disabled';
            thisMonth.disabled = null;
        }
        function drawThisMonth () {
            if (data2 != null) {
                chart.setDataTable(data2);
                table.setDataTable(data2);
                chart.draw();
                table.draw();
                lastMonth.disabled = null;
                thisMonth.disabled = 'disabled';
            }
            else {
                var query2 = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/a/csd99.org/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkmXRMp1VYawdFVEUmJlM3AzOUM3R0NMVlBzOTN5dlE&usp=drive_web\n\\n\&gid=2&headers=1');
                query2.send(function (response) {
                    if (response.isError()) {
                        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                        return;
                    }
                    data2 = response.getDataTable();
                    drawThisMonth();
                });
            }
        }

        if (document.addEventListener) {
            lastMonth.addEventListener('click', drawLastMonth);
            thisMonth.addEventListener('click', drawThisMonth);
        }
        else if (document.attachEvent) {
            lastMonth.attachEvent('onclick', drawLastMonth);
            thisMonth.attachEvent('onclick', drawThisMonth);
        }
        else {
            lastMonth.onclick = drawLastMonth;
            thisMonth.onclick = drawThisMonth;
        }
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['controls'], callback: drawCharts});
```

[HTML]

```
<h3>Data for gauges located in this sheet on worksheets 1 and 2</h3>
<h3><a href = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkmXRMp1VYawdFVEUmJlM3AzOUM3R0NMVlBzOTN5dlE&usp=sharing'> here.</a></h3>
<div id='gauge_div' style='height: 150px; width: 500px;'></div>
<div id='table_div'></div>
<input id="lastMonth" type="button" disabled="disabled" value="Last Month" />
<input id="thisMonth" type="button" value="This Month" />
```

see working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/n2xK9/

Comment: Thank you for this, it is very helpful.  It solves some other problems that you can see I'd been struggling with.  Can you help me understand what the `document.querySelector('#lastMonth')` and the `lastMonth.disabled = null` lines are doing?

Comment: `document.querySelector('#lastMonth')` gets the input with the `id` `'lastMonth'` (the `querySelector` method is a generic, more powerful means of getting elements from HTML by using CSS selectors instead of the methods `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName`, etc).  `lastMonth.disabled = null` re-enables the `'lastMonth'` button, making it clickable again.

Comment: When I try to put this all together I get inconsistent loading.  Usually the gauge_div is empty, but occasionally it loads fine.  My script seems very sensitive to whether I have the #gid or &gid and the &headers=1 in the query source URLs.  Sometimes the page will load fine.  I make a change, it doesn't work.  Then after reverting back to the original, it no longer loads.  Any ideas?  I'd like to show my complete code, but am not sure where to do that.  Thank you for your patience and attention.  Seems somehow connected to whether I've opened up the google sheet that's feeding the gauge.

Comment: You need to use `&gid` not `#gid`.  Here's a jsfiddle you can update with your current code: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/94gE9/

Comment: ok...more confused now.  code works fine in the jsfiddle, but I can't get the gauge to load when I run this as a local .html file.  I think I'm struggling with script tags, the google.load function, and permissions on my google sheet (though the sheet is public to view).  Should I pose a new question and include my full html there?    Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, open a new question with the HTML that is causing you problems.

Comment: Finally figured this one out.  There were & in the URLs for my google sheets that were not escaped properly.  Put those in, and the local html loads fine now.  Thanks again.  I learned a lot here.

Comment: Ok, for completeness it wasn't the URLs, although escaping the & in the URLs did work...for a moment.  The problem was with my use of google's autoload, which they fairly describe as tricky to implement here: [https://developers.google.com/loader/?csw=1#Dynamic].  I eliminated the autoload and now it's working consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `drawTable()` resulted in error message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Sw is not defined`

It seems that `table` package is not loaded using autoload. I added the following line to load packages:

```
    ...
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['gauge', 'table']});

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    ...
```

and got the following:

[image]